# NOT FOUND using restclient

Tags: groovy, payment-gateway, rest-client, httpbuilder

My request looks like this but when I try to run this code I get this error:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.httpbuilder',module='http-builder', version='0.7')

import groovy.json.JsonOutput

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException


public PaymentSpring() throws Exception {
def username ='test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
def resp
def https = new RESTClient('https://api.paymentspring.com/api/v1')
https.auth.basic(username,'')
def charge= [
    card_owner_name        : 'test tset',
    card_number      : '345829002709133',
    card_exp_month:'12',
    card_exp_year : '2015',
    csc:'999',
    amount:'100.00',
    email_address:'ujdieu@yahoo.com',
    send_receipt   : true
]
 try    {
    resp = https.post(
    path:'/charge',
    requestContentType: URLENC,//request content synchronously for the     "headers"
    headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    body:charge
)

} catch(HttpResponseException ex) {
    println ex
}
  println resp
```

the result:

```
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found
null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base URI was specified incorrectly - it should be hostname only - without any path. The following script works but fails with 401:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder',module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
@Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-log4j12', version='1.7.7')
@Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='jcl-over-slf4j', version='1.7.7')

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*


def username ='test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

def https = new RESTClient('https://api.paymentspring.com/')
https.auth.basic(username, '')

def charge = [
    card_owner_name  : 'test tset',
    card_number      : '345829002709133',
    card_exp_month   : '12',
    card_exp_year    : '2015',
    csc              : '999',
    amount           : '100.00',
    email_address    : 'ujdieu@yahoo.com',
    send_receipt     : true,
]

try {
    def resp = https.post(
        path:'api/v1/charge',
        requestContentType: URLENC,
        headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
        body:charge,
    )
} catch(HttpResponseException e) {
    r = e.response
    println("Success: $r.success")
    println("Status:  $r.status")
    println("Reason:  $r.statusLine.reasonPhrase")
    println("Content: \n${JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(r.data))}")
}
```

Comment: While this does in fact work, you can also just take the / at the beginning of the path and add it to the URI and the original post would have also worked.